# GWT how to submit datebox inside form

Tags: java, forms, gwt

In my gwt application I have a FormPanel and inside it there is a DateBox. The issue is DateBox doesn't have the "name" attribute so how can I submit the DateBox value to the server using the form's POST request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The issue is DateBox doesn't have the "name" attribute:

You can set name attribute to `DateBox`, since it has `TextBox`:

```
DateBox dateBox = new DateBox();
dateBox.getTextBox().setName(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a `DateBox`, use the [DateBox.getValue()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.5/com/google/gwt/user/datepicker/client/DateBox.html#getValue%28%29) method to obtain a [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object. Once you have reference to the `Date` object, you can use the `Date` objects various methods to obtain and format the date value, or simply call [Date.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29).

```
Date date = dateBox.getValue();
String dateValue = date.toString();
```

Edit: Misunderstood the question. To set the name of the `DateBox` to submit the form

```
dateBox.getTextBox().setName("dateBox");
```